# Getting circle vector from OpenCV Mat in Android?

Tags: java, android, opencv

I can't get the circle vectors values from the OpenCV Mat in Android. I want to use this function:

```
HoughCircles(Mat image, Mat circles, int method, double dp, double minDist)
```

And then I want to show the circles that were found. Where I'm stuck is how to use the `circles` parameter in this function.

So, the question is: how can I get numbers of 3-element vectors and values of every element in vector from Mat type of OpenCV in Android?

Comment: hi  did u get a solution to this one??

Answer (score 2):

Once you have your circles `Mat`

```
for (int i = 0; i < circles.cols(); i++)
{
    double vCircle[] = circles.get(0,i);
    double x = vCircle[0];
    double y = vCircle[1];
    double radius = vCircle[2];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you would want to use a `vector<Vec3f>` list to process the circles like this:

```
vector<Vec3f> circles;

// do HoughCircles...

for(size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++)
{
    Vec3f circle = circles[i];
    Point2f center(circle[0] /* x */, circle[1] /* y */);
    float radius = circle[2];

    // use the circle...
}
```

**EDIT :** I tried the code just using  a `Mat`, and it appears that the circle parameters are stored as a `1xN` matrix with elements of type `CV_32FC3`, and where `N` is the number of circles detected. So, each column contains the `(x, y, radius)` vector you need.

Here is a sample I wrote in C++ showing this:

```
Mat circleImage = imread("circle.png", 0);
Mat circleDisp;

cvtColor(circleImage, circleDisp, CV_GRAY2RGB);

Mat circles;
HoughCircles(circleImage, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2, circleImage.rows >> 2, 200, 100);

for( size_t i = 0; i < circles.cols; i++ )
{
    Vec3f vCircle = circles.at<Vec3f>(i);

    Point center(cvRound(vCircle[0]), cvRound(vCircle[1]));
    int radius = cvRound(vCircle[2]);
    // draw the circle center
    circle( circleDisp, center, 3, Scalar(0,255,0), -1, 8, 0 );
    // draw the circle outline
    circle( circleDisp, center, radius, Scalar(0,0,255), 3, 8, 0 );
}
namedWindow( "circles", 1 );
imshow( "circles", circleDisp );
waitKey();
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: But I need it for Java in Android. It's good  for C++, but doesn't work for Java.

Comment: @EvgenyEkim Could you tell me what the size of the `Mat circles` parameter is? I have an idea, but the size will help my answer be more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Just cast your Mat to vector:

```
HoughCircles(Mat image, Mat circles, int method, double dp, double minDist);

vector<Vec3f> myCircles = (vector<Vec3f>)circles;
```

Or, simpler

```
HoughCircles(Mat image, vector<Vec3f>& circles, 
          int method, double dp, double minDist);
```

**Note**

This is only true for OpenCV 2.3.1.